# Impersonation in Sharepoint 2010 via SoapClient in PHP

Tags: php, sharepoint-2010, impersonation, soap-client

I'd like to impersonate users in Sharepoint while using SoapClient to fetch list information, say.

My understanding is that I need to get a user token from Sharepoint for the user I'd like to impersonate, which I can then use to perform any other calls as that user.

All I can find is information to do this in C#, but I need to be able to do this entirely in PHP, and ideally via `SoapClient`.

Here is some background info about Impersonation in Sharepoint, including code snippets in C#:

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/